# How should I configure Jetty 7 pre3 to use oracle JDBC source?

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, jetty, jndi

All stuff is running under Windows XP Pro SP2/32-bit.

I have downloaded Jetty 7 pre3 from http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-7.0.0-prereleases/jetty-7.0.0pre3/jetty-assembly-7.0.0pre3.zip>dist.codehaus.org.
I have extracted jetty to `C:\jetty-7.0.0pre3\` (so I have C:\jetty-7.0.0pre3\bin\ and other dirs)
I have put my webapp into `C:\jetty-7.0.0pre3\webapps\`

I have resource-ref in my web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <description>dev datasource</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/dev</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and did configuration in jetty.xml:

```
<Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
</Array>

<New id="dev" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
  <Arg>jdbc/dev</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
      <Set name="User">username</Set>
      <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.201.201.64:1521:DEV</Set>
      <Set name="Password">password</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>

<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
      <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
      <Set name="webAppDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps</Set>
      <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">false</Set>
         <Set name="extract">true</Set>
         <Set name="allowDuplicates">false</Set>
      <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
      <Set name="ConfigurationClasses"><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

I'm running `java -DOPTION=plus -jar start.jar` from `C:\jetty-7.0.0pre3\` and I'm getting following error:

```
2008-10-14 12:12:49.163::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2008-10-14 12:12:49.413::WARN:  Config error at <New id="dev" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource"><Arg>jdbc/dev</Arg><Arg>
    <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"><Set name="User">username</Set><Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.201.201.64:1521:DEV</Set><Set name="Password">password</Set></New>
  </Arg></New>
2008-10-14 12:12:49.413::WARN:  EXCEPTION
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:572)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:256)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:214)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:971)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:564)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:136)
```

`C:\jetty-7.0.0pre3\lib\plus\jetty-plus-7.0.0pre3.jar` is on the classpath. In the same console:

```
C:\jetty-7.0.0pre3>set classpath
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\providerutil.jar;C:\Program
 Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSpher
e MQ\Java\lib\ldap.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\jta.jar;C:\Pro
gram Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\jndi.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\
Java\lib\jms.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\connector.jar;C:\Pro
gram Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\Java\lib\fscontext.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSpher
e MQ\Java\lib\com.ibm.mq.jar;.;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_05\classes;C:\Prog
ram Files\Java\jre1.5.0_05\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_05\
lib\spring.jar;c:\jetty-7.0.0pre3\lib\plus\jetty-plus-7.0.0pre3.jar
```

What's wrong? How should I add `org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource` to the visibility area of start.jar?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that addLifeCycle does not take a `Resource` object; it takes `LifeCycle` implementations such as `WebAppContext`s or `WebAppDeployer`s.

Assuming you have a WebAppDeployer (or equivalent) set up in your jetty.xml, try this:

```
<Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
  <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
</Array>

<Call name="addLifeCycle">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
      ....
      <Set name="ConfigurationClasses"><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Set>
      ....
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>


<New id="dev" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
  <Arg>jdbc/dev</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource">
      <Set name="User">username</Set>
      <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.201.201.64:1521:DEV</Set>
      <Set name="Password">password</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

If you want the datasource only for a particular webapp, then do a similar configuration  within a jetty-env.xml file for that webapp.

Also, since you're using Jetty 7, you will need to load the (optional) `plus` libraries (if the exe isn't doing that for you already). You'll know they aren't being loaded, because you'll get a ClassNotFoundException on startup.

Starting up Jetty on Linux, I would do it like so:

```
java -DOPTIONS=plus -jar start.jar
```

However, I am not familiar with Windows. Possibly

```
Jetty-Service.exe -DOPTIONS=plus
```

would work? If not, then look for something which would set the system property "OPTIONS" to "plus" when you run jetty.